# onUpgrade method from SQLiteOpenHelper never called when replacing the database file

Tags: android, sqlite

I know there are a lot of similar questions and I hope not being repeating but I tried different things and I am still unable to fix the issue. I am developing an Android app that uses SQLite to store some data internally. I have been using this app in my own phone for a month and I added lot of data I do not want to lose, but at the same time I have been improving the app in my computer, but the improvements made me change some column names, adding some columns and tables. So, right now I want to update the app in my phone.

The previous version had the database set to 2 and the new one is 3. In addition, my app has the ability to create backups of the database just copying the file to the SDcard, and the ability to restore it by replacing the internal database file for one that the user selects from the sd card. Now the problem is that I did a backup of the database from the phone and I moved it to my computer to import it in the new version of the app running in an emulator to ensure the app can upgrade the database as expected before I install the new version on my phone. The problem is that onUpgrade for the SQLiteOpenHelper is never called. I did different trials but nothing is working. I can ensure the database from my phone has version 2 (I used sqliteadmin "PRAGMA user_version;" SQL query and answers 2) and my app looks for version 3. The app crashes as it is unable to find the new tables.

Here you have the code executed when importing a backup:

```
private boolean importDatabase(String path) {  
    String dbPath = mDbHelper.getDbPath();  
    mDbHelper.close();  

    boolean result = copyFile(path, dbPath);  

    if (result) {  
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);  
        mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().close();  
    }  
    return result;  
}
```

I have to mention as well that when the user reaches the place to import/export the database in the new version, a new empty database with version 3 has been created as the app needs an active database from the stating activity. Then, when importing, this empty database file is replaced by the imported one. I wonder if there is any cached data I am missing to clean.

Could you give me some clues to understand why onUpgrade is never called in this scenario?